# sync submodule that is a fork with original repo

Tags: git, workflow, git-submodules

I have a 'super-repository' that has a submodule that is essentially a fork of an original repository (with my changes). What would be a possible workflow I can use to merge with the latest changes on the master branch of the original repository into the submodule? In other words, I want to update the submodule to the latest changes.

I imagine I'd have to add a remote representing that original repository. So I went into the submodule's directory and added the remote, then tried `git pull origin master`, then in the super-repo I did `git add the-submodule`, commit and push. However, on another computer when I tried to do `git pull && git submodule update`, I got the following error:

> fatal: reference is not a tree: 1790434a80cca4173677c9a21ffd80a50cc970ef
>
> Unable to checkout '1790434a80cca4173677c9a21ffd80a50cc970ef' in submodule path 'oh-my-zsh'

So I imagine I'm doing it wrong. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you add the remote of the original repo in the submodule repo itself, or did you add the remote to the config of the parent repo?

Comment: @VonC: I added it to the submodule repo itself. I went into the submodule's directory and did git remote add there. Will add this info to the question.

Comment: On the other repo, after the (buggy) `git submodule update`, do you still get a submodule content, and does its `.git/config` file contain the right remote address?

Comment: @VonC: I'm not sure I understand your question. However, I did manage to revert that buggy conflict.

Comment: ok I was making sure the local config of the submodule repo did still contain the remote repo address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up starting from scratch, it worked.